# Jquery mobile datebox today button close on click

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-mobile

I'm using the jquery mobile datebox from here: http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox/ and I am setting the calTodayButton to true. The problem I have is when I click the button it just selects today's date which is fine but I also want it to close on click. Any ideas as to the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding an click event to the button which closes the parent container like this

```
$('.ui-datebox-controls').find('a.ui-btn').on("click",function(){
    $(this).parent().parent('.ui-datebox-container').hide();
 });
```

Comment: Do you know where I should put that code? Because I haven't actually made a button myself, i've just used a    data-options='{"mode": "calbox", "calTodayButton": true}'

Comment: Hey never mind mate I put it with the rest of the javascript and works, thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted solution didn't work for me, but this one did:

```
$('.ui-datebox-controls').find('a.ui-btn').live( 'click', function(){
    $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent('.ui-datebox-container').hide();
});
```