# How to detect clear/close from set in jQueryMobile DateBox?

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, datebox

I'm using jQuery Mobile DateBox (in mode "timebox") to make the user select a time.

This works fine, but both hitting the top-left *close* icon and the *Set Time* button result in the same callback with the same arguments.

I'm looking for a way to make the close button just dismiss the control.

I found [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9815613/jquery-mobile-datebox-today-button-close-on-click) here, but I fear that the DOM for the control has changed as `$('.ui-datebox-controls')` gives an empty result. I can't find the control in the DOM either.

So, I hoped for `openCallBack` or `beforeOpenCallBack` to realise a similar trick, but neither appear to be called.

Comment: `$(document).on("click", ".ui-datebox-container .ui-btn", function (e) {` should work.

Comment: I tried that too and must have made typo :-(  Thanks.  Unfortunately it does not work to hide and do ev,preventDefault() for some reason.  Now set a global variable to indicate when the delete button was clicked and consider the closeHandler a dismiss of the delete button was hit less than a second earlier ...  Not nice, but it works.